# Environment align with composed objects

Tags: align

I have some equation with the align environment:

```
\begin{align}
  E &= A + B + C + D + E \\
    &\underbrace{=}_{C + D + E = 2B} A + 3B
\end{align}
```

the result is

[image]
However I would like to get aligned both "=" symbols. Any idea?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8hi1.png) seems like a far easier representation of what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

i suspect that you like to have something like this:

[image]

(at least from math point of view is more logical)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
E & = A + B + \underbrace{C + D + E}_{C+D+E=2B} \\
  & = A + 3B
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the purpose, there are also other possibilities like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
E & = A + B + C + D + E \\
  & ~\rnode[c]{eq}{=} A + 3B
  \qquad\ovalnode[shadow=true]{rel}{C+D+E=2B}\ncarc[arcangle=28,arcangleB=45]{->}{rel}{eq}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, this is less suited for some scientific article, but in other situations it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, bm} %% load amsmath

\usepackage{makebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A & = A + B + C + D + E \\
   & \mathrel{\makebox*{=}{$ \underbrace{{}={}}_{C + D + E = 2B} $}} A + 3B
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  A & = A + B + C + D + E \\
   & \underset{\mathclap{\substack{\enspace\boldsymbol{\uparrow}\\[-0.3ex]\overbrace{\scriptstyle C + D + E = 2B}}}}{=} A + 3B
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]